# how can I capture **http response** from twitter.com? ( ruby + twitter gem)

Tags: ruby, twitter, twitter-client

I opened a question [how can I capture response from twitter.com? ( ruby + twitter gem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679784/how-can-i-capture-response-from-twitter-com-ruby-twitter-gem) to know if my update was successful. It is working fine...

But I would like to know how I can capture [**HTTP Response Codes and Errors**](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/HTTP-Response-Codes-and-Errors) inside my ruby code?

```
oauth = Twitter::OAuth.new('consumer token', 'consumer secret')
oauth.authorize_from_access('access token', 'access secret')

client = Twitter::Base.new(oauth)
response = client.update('Heeeyyyyoooo from Twitter Gem!')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use firefox with the [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) addon installed, it displays http response codes on it's "NET" tab.

Or do you need to do this from within your app?